# How can I return a Dragged Object From a Layer Group to its Original Position?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to work on a card system, I have a drag system going nicely and the cards are setup on a horizontal layer group, however, when the player drops the card outside of the "casting area" I would like it to return to it's original position before it was dragged. Because of the layer group, even though I'm storing the original position having it go back to it produces funkiness and going below the "card hand" area.

I've tried Update and Coroutine approaches using something like this:

```
 IEnumerator CardReturn(Transform card, Vector3 destination, float speed)
 {

     while (transform.position != destination)
     {
         card.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(
             card.position,
             destination,
             speed * Time.deltaTime);

         yield return null;
     }
```

transform is the object transform and destination is the original position of the object placed at the start method.

Just to be clear, I want the card to physically move back, not just snap back.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Update: I have tried swapping a place holder in the position, here are images of what happens in that case: 1. Starting hand, 2. Placeholder in position for the card when pulled, 3. What happens when the card attempts to return to that position.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you considered adding an invisible placeholder object to the horizontal layout group in the desired order, to hold space for the card that's still mid-transition, and then swapping the transiting card into place once it's arrived at the same position as the placeholder?

Comment: Hi DMGregory, I did try this, I've updated my questions with images of what happens. When it returns to place it has an offset and I'm not sure what to do about it, I've used the placeholder position as well as the actually hard coded position at start and no luck.